# productsRequest response method is not calling

Tags: iphone, cocoa, in-app-purchase

I am implementing an in app purchase and I am sending the request to apple store through

```
- (void) requestProductData
{
 SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:
         [NSSet setWithObjects: featureAId,featureBId,nil]]; // add any other product here
 request.delegate = self;
 [request start];
}
```

the response method

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
 [purchasableObjects addObjectsFromArray:response.products];
}
```

is not getting called at all. Only once did it call out of ten attempts I tried.

Answer (score 48):

Try to implement also `- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` method - may be there're some errors in processing of your requests.

Comment: thanks Vladmir..... i get problem that is due to internet connection problem in my device

Comment: i tried that method also due to sever problem no call back that time

Comment: +1 needed that function header. When no internet connection ofc this will be called...

Comment: I wondered how Vladimir found this. SKProductsRequest subclasses SKRequest which has an SKRequestDelegate. SKProductsRequestDelegate conforms to  SKRequestDelegate so your class can implement this method, and it will tell you useful things like, "StoreKit doesn't work in iOS Simulator, you idiot."

Answer (score 28):

I faced the same problem, but in my case the cause was that I was using **Automatic Reference Counting** and I forgot to retain the request.

My code was like:

```
- (void) requestProductData
{
    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:ProductIdentifier]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}
```

But delegate's productsRequest:didReceiveResponse: never got called.

A fix would be:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProductsRequest *request;

- (void) requestProductData
{
    self.request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:ProductIdentifier]];
    self.request.delegate = self;
    [self.request start];
    // you can nil request property in request:didFailWithError: and requestDidFinish:
}
```

Comment: Seems like this has been fixed by Apple as once you call `start` on a request, it now seems to retain itself and thus will stay alive until it ultimately failed or succeeded (iOS 8 at least; haven't tested with iOS 7 yet).

Comment: I didn't have this problem in iOS, but now that I've migrated to macOS with Mac Catalyst, I'm seeing the problem and creating a property to retain the request seems to fix it.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem.  I had created a helper class to handle the IAP and check for the products.  What I finally found was the instance of the class I created was being released before the response came back, thus the delegate methods never got called because they did not exist anymore.

I solved my problem by retaining the instance of the helper class in the class I called it from using @proprty(strong, nonatomic)...

If you are not using a helper class and coding it into an existing class then the answer above will work by retaining your SKProductRequest.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem (error: Cannot connect to iTunes Store). After upgrading iTunes Beta to the latest version it started working again.

Comment: I had a similar issue. The request was retained and wasn't failing or succeeding, but rebooting the phone made it work again.