# SKProductsRequest - No Response Now (was working - same code)

Tags: iphone, sdk, in-app-purchase, storekit

Code as following - this code worked yesterday are providing invalid ID's now longer works, i've been though code about 10 times

.m

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface InAppViewController : UIViewController  <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver> {

    SKProduct *proUpgradeProduct;
    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
}
```

.h

```
#import "InAppViewController.h"


@implementation InAppViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [self requestProUpgradeProductData];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData
{
    NSLog(@"called  productsRequest");

    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:@"com.okz8.investor.gem15" ];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];

    // we will release the request object in the delegate callback
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate methods

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *products = response.products;
    proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [[products firstObject] retain] : nil;
    if (proUpgradeProduct)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }

    // finally release the reqest we alloc/init’ed in requestProUpgradeProductData
    [productsRequest release];

    //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}
```

This just does not return response i've done all here http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

Was getting invalid ID's now i dont get anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same problem and found the solution here:
[productsRequest response method is not calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728874/productsrequest-response-method-is-not-calling)

Due to automatic reference counting my request was immediately deleted again...

Answer (score 6):

Based on user178379 response, Try to implement this method:

```
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"request - didFailWithError: %@", [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSLocalizedDescription"]);
}
```

My problem was: `Cannot connect to iTunes Store`, which was for:

```
StoreKit (In-App purchases) will not work in the Simulator. 13962338
```

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem in an iOS 15 device.

```
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

is also implemented, and also not called.

Reboot of device and it all worked again!

When this happens I get this, or similar, in the log:

```
[BackgroundTask] Background Task 6 ("SKProductsRequest"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, it seems, that in the case, when the set of product identifiers being passed during the construction of a  `SKProductsRequest` is empty, neither of the `SKProductsRequestDelegate` delegate functions are called.